# how do automate testing form with upload file inside using Feature Test in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

need your help.

i tried to test my controller that have an form with file uploads, my test is using Feature Test codeigniter 4.
i made some test for that, and i using `faker->image()` to generate images that can be use for upload files.

```
$this->post(route_to('app-form-uploads'), [
            "name" => "9804492801928802",
            "image_path" => $faker->image()
      ]);
```

the image path valued `c://users/..../..../local/temp/yoiuhku1yadgJHGJYty767.png`
and if i check in directories file is exists.

but the validation show the errors like :

```
["image_path"] => string(74) "image_path is not a valid uploaded file."
```

how to do that, how to test form with upload file in codeigniter using featured test ?

Comment: Unfortunately cannot be done - issue has been around since day dot and as of October 2021 it isn't possible. Only solution is to send a Post flag over to your code with a file and bypass your upload mechanism if you're happy the posted data is clean.